# Remove params from URL with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, url

I have this URL `value/value/34c9619d/documents`

`34c9619d` : this part is variable and I want to delete it from my string.

I want to get something like value/value/[id]/documents

How can I do it ? Maybe with regex ?

Comment: Hi, have you tried anything? Please share what you've tried and we can help if you have issues.

Comment: I don't know regex so I don't really know if it's possible. I've try tried things with the router but the project is complex and use differents routing library so I think it's gonna be more easier with regex maybe

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a regex can do the trick:

```
str.replace(/value\/\w+\/documents/g, "value/[id]/documents")
```

The `\w` means every alphanumeric character, repeated one or several times (`+`).

Comment: I should have clarified that `value` can also change like `documents` and the id can comport underscores